# Why does using ffmpeg avcodec_send_frame function cause Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

the cpp code:

[gist code](https://gist.github.com/vaptu/5ea12f86f1f229cec5186637c960713b)

Calling avcodec_send_frame on line 148 throws an error

debug info:
[image]

Thank you very much for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: Please delete the C tag if it's C++ code.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Somethings seems off to me when I looked at your code. Like you don't check packet types whether it is audio, video, etc. Check ffmpeg official transcoding example here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c

Hope that helps.